# JQuery function throwing "missing ) after argument list" error and I can't see why

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

The JQuery Code is running below, and then for some reason it is throwing that error. I have combed through it a few times. Maybe I am just blind. Could anyone spot the error?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.timeselectendcurrent').click(function () {
        if ($('.timeselectendcurrent').is(':checked')){
            $('.timeselectend').prop('disabled': true);
            alert('it worked!');
        }
        else {
            $(".timeselectend").prop('disabled': false);
            alert("it turned off!");
        }
    });
});
```

Error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

It says this is happening on Line 4: `$('.timeselectend').prop('disabled': true);`

Comment: put comma in place of colon with prop API -  $(".timeselectend").prop('disabled', false);

Comment: $('jquerySelector').prop( propertyName ); = Get the value of a property for the first element in the set of matched elements.
& 
$('jquerySelector').prop( propertyName, value ); = Set one or more properties for the set of matched elements.
http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use comma `,` to separate arguments op [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of colon `:`.

```
$('.timeselectend').prop('disabled', true); // Disable
//                                 ^

$('.timeselectend').prop('disabled', false); // Enable
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('.timeselectend').prop({'disabled': true}); // use `{}`
```

Or this:

```
$('.timeselectend').prop('disabled', true); // use `,` instead of `:`
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `:`  with comma `,`  in

```
$('.timeselectend').prop('disabled': true);
$(".timeselectend").prop('disabled': false);
```

change to this

```
$('.timeselectend').prop('disabled', true);
$(".timeselectend").prop('disabled', false);
```